# Como automatizar testes?

Tags: servidor, testes, deploy

É comum a cada vez que ocorre o deploy um bug ir junto, muitas vezes percebido somente meses depois daquela alteração. Para solucionar isso,  quero saber se é possível testar **TODAS as funcionalidades principais de forma automatizada?** Digo, antes de ir para a produção o **teste de integração** executará e se falhar não irá subir. 
 Além disso,  há outra opção a não ser criar vários testes JUnit?

Comment: Da forma como está, essa pergunta é muito ampla. Existem [diversos tipos de teste](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teste_de_software#Fases_ou_N.C3.ADveis) (unitários, de regressão, de integração...), alguns mais automatizáveis e outros menos. A forma de inseri-los no seu fluxo de trabalho, a forma de utilizar suas ferramentas de desenvolvimento/*deploy* para auxiliar nisso, etc, também são variadas. Por favor especifique mais a pergunta, se quiser saber "como automatizar os testes de unidade JUnit na plataforma X" ou "pra que serve o teste Y e quando utilizá-lo", isso já é mais "respondível".

Comment: Além do @mgibsonbr disse, procure sobre Continuous Integration. Sem dúvidas vai te ajudar, apesar de não estar diretamente relacionado.

Comment: Me parece que o Jenkins seria a resposta que você quer. É possível com ele fazer um processo de build que após a compilação, ele execute os testes e automaticamente coloque em produção se todos eles passarem (e deixe de fazer isso caso falhem). No entanto como não entendo muito de Jenkins e faz tempo que não mexo com ele, deixo isso apenas como um comentário e não como uma resposta.

Comment: É possível fazer-se testes sem usar o JUnit. Um programa dentro de um `public static void main(String[])` que saia invocando todas as funcionalidades do sistema para testá-lo já seria alguma coisa. Uma alternativa ao JUnit é o TestNG. Existem plug-ins para o JUnit e para o TestNG para cobrir deficiências de ambos. E no final, testes automáticos (ainda) não caem do céu, pois em algum momento você deverá escrevê-los.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um software muito utilizado é o **Jenkis** que através dele, é possível agilizar tarefas demoradas como a compilação de um projeto e a execução dos seus testes automatizados. Com um servidor de integração contínua bem configurado, essas tarefas são executadas a cada mudança no repositório de código e, em caso de erros de compilação ou falhas nos testes automatizados, todos os desenvolvedores são alertados rapidamente. Dessa forma, se o servidor de integração não aponta problemas no projeto, a equipe tem a segurança de que as mudanças no código estão de acordo com a bateria de testes. É também um passo na direção do deploy contínuo.

Muitas pessoas que são adeptas ao **Open Source**, já que esse tem suporte e é provido pela comunidade diretamente. Se integra com repositórios Git, SVN, CVS, e builds com Maven, Ant, Gradle etc. Roda num Servlet Container, o que facilita no caso de você já ter um servidor de aplicação rodando num servidor de testes, por exemplo. Mas se você não tiver, tudo bem: ele tem uma versão “executável”, que não é standalone, mas que faz o serviço de auto-deploy dele mesmo pra você. Configurado o repositório do controle de versão para o seu projeto, está feito: é só executar os builds pelo dashboard, que te dá as informações resumidas do build e acesso ao console. Executa os testes unitários como no seu caso **JUnit**, inclusive integrados ao Selenium e outras ferramentas de testes de aceitação. Deu erro? Envia e-mail e até SMS.